# how to fix "Package pcre-6.6-6.el5_6.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version" alert need to update it to pcre-8.31?

Tags: linux, centos, pcre

Goodafternoon,

I am trying to update my pcre-6.6-6.el5_6.1.x86_64 package to pcre-8.31 following is my steps to do so:

Step

1: cd /etc/yum.repos.d

2. Made repository utter-ramblings.repo in it.
3. Populated utter-ramblings.repo file with

   ```
   [utter-ramblings]
   name=Utter Ramblings
   baseurl=http://www.jasonlitka.com/media/EL5/i386/
   gpgkey=http://www.jasonlitka.com/media/RPM-GPG-KEY-jlitka
   enabled=1
   gpgcheck=1
   ```
4. Then following command:

   ```
   yum install pcre
   ```

I got installation process started successfully but with following errors

```
    Transaction Check Error:
    file /usr/share/man/man1/pcregrep.1.gz from install of pcre-8.13-1.jason.2.i386   conflicts with file from package pcre-6.6-6.el5_6.1.x86_64
```

file /usr/share/man/man1/pcretest.1.gz from install of pcre-8.13-1.jason.2.i386 conflicts with file from package pcre-6.6-6.el5_6.1.x86_64

My OS at VPS info is: OS
        Linux 2.6.18-028stab094.3

Kindly help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update both archs of `pcre` in the same transaction:

```
yum update pcre.{i386,x86_64}
```

provided, of course, you have a 64-bit copy of this newer `pcre` as well. Failing that, remove pcre.x86_64 first before attempting to upgrade the 32-bit copy of `pcre` -- though I'd recommend doing it the other way around and keeping only the 64-bit copy.

Comment: Is it right to remove older pcre-6.6 first and then install pcre-8.31.

Comment: Might not be a good idea if you have many packages depending on it. In that case, if you're rolling out your own newer pcre package, consider renaming it to pcre8 or something

Comment: Try configuring this repo as well: http://www.jasonlitka.com/media/EL5/x86_64/ -- and see if you can then update both pcre together

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, and was able to solve it by running:

- yum remove pcre.i386
- yum update pcre

The list of packages depending on *only* the i386 architecture was much smaller than for the entire package (mostly kde in my case) - your mileage may vary, please consider the listed dependencies carefully before accepting the removal.

After this, the 64-bit architecture updated properly to the 8.13-1.jason.2 version.

On another note, I also had to run

- yum reinstall grep

As it seemed to be linking to the no-longer existing library.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can manually install it by downloading RPMs : http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/21060862/dir/redhat_el_5/com/pcre-devel-8.13-1.jason.1.i386.rpm.html

Answer (score 0):

You've specified *both* the wrong distribution and the wrong architecture in your third party repository configuration.

```
.../EL5/i386/...
```

But, you're running EL6 on x86_64!

So, instead, this should read:

```
.../EL6/x86_64/...
```